# LinearLayout and Visibility GONE issue

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, visibility

Alright, so I'm running into a rather odd problem. I think I'm doing this right, but something  weird happens when I try to set the visibility to GONE on any of my linear layouts.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use a spinner onItemSelected listener to determine which layouts are visible. It's basically a table row, spinner, and three linearlayouts inside of one linearlayout inside of a scrollview inside of a RelativeLayout. Here's the first xml of part of it, just not showing the other 2 linearlayouts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Catbug" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|fill_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/catbug_quotes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/catbugback"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/backbuttonpress" android:contentDescription="@string/goback"/>

        </TableRow>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/catbugspinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/catbug7_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Now, here's the code side of the part in question:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final   LinearLayout ep7 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.catbug7_layout);
    final   LinearLayout ep10 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.catbug10_layout);
    final   LinearLayout ep11 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.catbug11_layout);
    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        ep7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ep10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ep11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1:
        ep7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ep10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ep11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 2:
        ep7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ep10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ep11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 3:
        ep7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ep10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ep11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }
}
```

In general, it works. The layouts I don't want for certain spinner choices disappear after they're selected and come to the top of the screen. However, they don't actually disappear until I start to scroll, which presents a problem as the first linearlayout doesn't NEED to scroll as only like 5 buttons are visible. However, an inactive (it's been destroyed, just still visible) linearlayout2 suddenly dissapears if I swipe my finger like I were intending to actually scroll.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? It's bugging the hell out of me because it actually works, it's just the aesthetic of having that weird "ghosting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your onItemSelected is only getting call when you clear focus from your spinner to any other space. Try to log and check when it is being called - when you select spinner or when you touch the screen. If it's the latter, you might want to revisit your code.

Alternatively your layout is not getting invalidated. If the onItemSelected is getting called properly, try invalidating the layout after you have hidden the views.

Comment: I'm still completely lost. I added an invalidate statement to invalidate the home_layout in each of the cases. Nothing changes. Also, as for logging, I have no idea how to do it correctly. I can see the log in eclipse while it's running, there's just nothing valuable there.

Sorry, I'm kind of new to programming with Android. I only have background in some basic c++ and visual c++

Comment: Never mind! I invalidated the ScrollView instead of the LinearLayout inside of it and it worked. I should've done that in the first place, seeing as it went away when I tried to scroll. Thank you so much!